# Disconnected after connecting to VPN when using remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, l2tp

I need to be able to remote desktop to a Windows 2008 machine and then from that machine connect to our corporate L2TP VPN. However, as soon as the VPN connects, the remote desktop session hangs and I need to reboot. I assume this has to do with the machine getting its routing table updated when it connects to the VPN. Is there any way to do this? I have full admin control over both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the VPN connection is configured to use the gateway on the remote network (VPN network). Try disabling that option in the VPN properties.

Comment: Hi yes, that works, I no longer get disconnected but then none of the traffic is routed through the VPN. Any way to fix that?

Comment: You need to adjust the routing table to keep your RDP traffic off the VPN, but allow the other traffic to go over the VPN.  Without knowing the routing tables on both machines ("route print"), its hard to give a more detailed answer.